# How to validate text length for webtable fields inside particular column using Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I got a table with 5 columns: "Name", "Age" Gender" Occupation" and "Salary":

xpath of "Name" column header:

```
//button[@class='sort-header-btn' and text()='Name']
```

And its field xpath is:

```
//div[@row-id='"+DynamicName+"']//following-sibling::div[@cold-id='Name']
```

I need to verify that "Dynamic Name" **should not be exceed 10** String characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here you **passing** the `DynamicName` string as a parameter to locate the desired element.
If you want to verify this string name you can do that **before** passing this parameter to Selenium method.
This can be done as well after passing the parameter to Selenium method, but anyway since you **passing** this string as a parameter you always have it, so you can check this string length easily since you already have it value.

Comment: I need to check after passing the parameter to Selenium method, so how to do it?

Comment: Again. You already **have** this string value. You can check it length before or after passing it here, you not need to find it value since you already have it. You can simply apply `len(DynamicName)` on it

Answer (score 0):

Having read your question and the comment, I think what you are looking for is not the length of "Dynamic Name", but the length of the field's value of below xPath

```
//div[@row-id='"+DynamicName+"']//following-sibling::div[@cold-id='Name']
```

If that is the case, then just use the below code to print the length of the string of web element in this xPath

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@row-id='"+DynamicName+"']//following-sibling::div[@cold-id='Name']")).getText().length());
```